# Saving a worksheet to new workbook and rename based on cell value

Tags: vba, excel

I'm still new to vba, i have queries about on how to copy a worksheet to a new workbook and rename the new workbook based on cell value. i have a worksheet name as "Summary" and would like to copy the worksheet and export to new workbook but i also want the new workbook to be named according the a cell value ( which is in this case, i want it to be name according to cell B3 ). Below are the code that i have tried :

```
Sub Sample2()

    Dim wksht As Summary
    Set wksht = ActiveSheet

    Dim path As String
    path = "C:\Desktop"

        wksht.Copy
        ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs filename:=path & wksht.Range(B3).Value & ".xlsx"
End Sub
```

I've keep getting an error "user defined type is not define" . Could you guys help me on this ?

Thanks.

Comment: your wording (`I want it to be name according to cell B3`) doesn't match your code (`...& wksht.Range(B2)...`). And where and how is `wb` defined and initialized?

Comment: This part 'Range(B3).Value' , should be 'Range("B3").Value'

Comment: where is your B3 cell? in which Sheet?

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim wksht As Summary
```

Is the likely cause of your error! Type "Summary" is not a defined type.
You should change it to `Dim wksht as WorkSheet`

Answer (score 0):

Couple of things have to be changed:
1. As @PIT mentioned wksht has to be defined as WorkSheet and not as "Summary"
2. Assuming that you will run your macro from "Summary" sheet, your code will work otherwise you have to Set wksht to "Summary" worksheet.
3. You have to change Range(B3).Value to Range("B3").Value

overall I would suggest to explore Google, tons of samples on your case

```
Sub Sample2()

    Dim wksht As WorkSheet
    Set wksht = ActiveSheet

    Dim path As String
    path = "C:\Desktop\"

        wksht.Copy
        ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs filename:=path & wksht.Range("B3").Value & ".xlsx"
End Sub
```